# Javascript add/remove attribute for data-required="true"

Tags: javascript, jquery

**HTML**

```
<select name="CustomerType" id="CustomerType" class="form-control" onchange="CustomerTypeChange()">
    <option value="@((int)THOS.Utilities.Enumerations.Enumerations.Customer.CustomerType.Company)" selected="@(Model != null ? (Model.CustomerType == (int)THOS.Utilities.Enumerations.Enumerations.Customer.CustomerType.Company):true)">Company</option>
    <option value="@((int)THOS.Utilities.Enumerations.Enumerations.Customer.CustomerType.Person)" selected="@(Model != null ? ((Model.CustomerType == (int)THOS.Utilities.Enumerations.Enumerations.Customer.CustomerType.Person)) : false)">Person</option>
</select>

<input type="text" name="TaxNumber" id="TaxNumber" class="form-control parsley-validated">
```

When CustomerType change below js code runs

**Javascript Code:**

```
function CustomerTypeChange() {
    var customerType = document.getElementById("CustomerType").value;
    if (customerType == 10) {
        $('#TaxNumber').attr("data-required", 'false');
    }
    if (customerType == 20) {
        $("#TaxNumber").attr("data-required", 'true');
    }
}
```

When i add TaxNumber attribute true/false **attr("data-required", true)** or  **attr("data-required", false)** never works .

**Edited:**

```
 $("#TaxNumber").data('data-required', true); does not work too

 $("#TaxNumber").data('required', true); does not work too
```

If i check browser console there is no any error where i miss exactly ?

Thanks.

Comment: Use `.data()` like `$('#TaxNumber').data('required', true/false);` for details read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7261619/jquery-data-vs-attr

Comment: Edited please check my question @Satpal

Comment: instead of `$("#TaxNumber").data('data-required', true)` it should be only `$("#TaxNumber").data('required', true)`

Comment: @Kartikeya required does not work chedk edited

Comment: @John, Are you using any validation framework? A wild guess `$("#TaxNumber").attr('required', true);`

Comment: @Satpal: Not sure why so many comment upvotes, but you would never use `data` to set this as it must be a `data-`attribute (and not stored in the element data store - which later browsers would do). You must use `attr`.

Comment: @John Can you use `console.log(customerType)` and check if the value is actually correct.

Comment: Ignoring my suggested improvements below, your original code works too: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/CmW9e/2/. Are you expecting the validation to automatically pick up the change to the `data-required` attribute? If so what validation framework are you using, as many do not do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Suggested improvements:**

When using jQuery avoid connecting events via attributes. Also use jQuery for select value checking (using `val()`).

Remove the `onchange` attribute and try this instead:

```
// Shortcut DOM ready handler
$(function(){
    // Listen for change event
    $('#CustomerType').change(function(){
        // Use jQuery val() to get select values
         var customerType = $(this).val();
         if (customerType == 10) {
            $("#TaxNumber").attr("data-required", 'false');
         }
         if (customerType == 20) {
            $("#TaxNumber").attr("data-required", 'true');
         }
    });
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/CmW9e/1/

If you inspect the DOM you will see the `data-required` attribute is set correctly.

**Your original "works" too:**

Your original code also works: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/CmW9e/2/ so it is more likely the problem that your validation framework does not pickup dynamic changes to the required flag. *Is the issue actually that you expected the validation rules to update automatically based on that attribute?*

**Solution:**

Most validation frameworks allow you to change the rules client-side (add and remove rules etc), but you will need to provide details of the validation framework you are using to get a specific answer :)

Comment: I copied and pasted and checked,  data-required part is not working.